# More simplified way of creating page links dynamically?

Tags: php, pagination

well I have a working script (see below) but it seems quite clunky and redundant; in my defense I wrote this code many moons ago, but that's not the point. I was curious if anyone has an idea on a more efficient way of writing this code, with less loops and conditionals and, well, noise in the code.

Code in question:

```
private function pageLinks($num, $page = 1, $search = false, $ne = false) {
    $query = ($search) ? '&query='.$search : null;
    $by = (is_numeric($ne)) ? '&by='.$ne : null;
    $links = 'Page(s):<a href="search.php?page=1' . $query . $by . '" class="tableLink">1</a>';
    $count = 1;
    $npp = $this->numPerPage;
    $buttons = 9;
    $half = 4;
    for($i = 1; $i <= $num; $i++) {
        if(($i%$npp) === 0) {
            $count++;
        }
    }
    if($count < $buttons) {
        for($i = 2; $i <= $count; $i++) {
            $links .= '<a href="search.php?page=' . $i . $query . $by . '" class="tableLink">' . $i . '</a>';
        }
    } elseif($page <= ($half + 2)) {
        for($i = 2; $i <= $buttons; $i++) {
            $links .= '<a href="search.php?page=' . $i . $query . $by . '" class="tableLink">' . $i . '</a>';
        }
        $links .= '...<a href="search.php?page=' . $count . $query . $by . '" class="tableLink">' . $count . '</a>';
    } elseif($page <= ($count - ($half + 2))) {
        $links .= '...';
        for($i = $half; $i > 0; $i--) {
            $links .= '<a href="search.php?page=' . ($page - $i) . $query . $by . '" class="tableLink">' . ($page - $i) . '</a>';
        }
        $links .= '<a href="search.php?page=' . ($page - $i) . $query . $by . '" class="tableLink">' . ($page - $i) . '</a>';
        for($i = 1; $i <= $half; $i++) {
            $links .= '<a href="search.php?page=' . ($page + $i) . $query . $by . '" class="tableLink">' . ($page + $i) . '</a>';
        }
        $links .= '...<a href="search.php?page=' . $count . $query . $by . '" class="tableLink">' . $count . '</a>';
    } else {
        $links .= '...';
        for($i = $buttons - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
            $links .= '<a href="search.php?page=' . ($count - $i) . $query . $by . '" class="tableLink">' . ($count - $i) . '</a>';
        }
    }
    return($links);
}
```

The method is called like so:

```
$links = $this->pageLinks($count, $page, $url, $ne);
```

And the variables are as such:

`$count` = total number of clients in database `(int)`
`$page` = current page to build from `(int)`
`$url` = the name or email for the search `(String)`
`$ne` = is for the search string either by name (1) or email (2) `(int)`

And the output is something like (as links):

Page(s):`1` `2` `3` `4` `5` `6` `7` `8` `9`...`33`

Or if you're in the middle (page 20):

Page(s):`1`...`16` `17` `18` `19` `20` `21` `22` `23` `24`...`33`

Now this isn't always called through a search function, hence the default values for `$url` and `$ne`, but that's not very important. My question is there a cleaner way to handle building of these links? Or am I stuck with this cluster of loops?

Comment: You should ask this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @JaredFarrish thanks for the heads up, I just did.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the people at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) I found exactly what I needed. You can [find the answer here for a more in-depth approach](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29897/more-simplified-way-of-creating-page-links-dynamically), but here is the updated code if anyone comes across this and is curious:

```
private function pageLinks($num, $page = 1, $search = false, $ne = false) {
    $query = ($search && is_numeric($ne)) ? "&query=" . $search . "&by=" . $ne : null;
    $links = "Page(s):" . $this->page_link(1, $query);
    $npp = $this->numPerPage;
    $half = 4;
    $count = floor($num / $npp) + 1;
    $from = $page - $half;
    if($from <= 2) {
        $from = 2;
    }
    $to = $page + $half;
    if($to >= $count - 1) {
        $to = $count - 1;
    }
    if($from > 2) {
        $links .= "...";
    }
    for($i = $from; $i <= $to; $i++) {
        $links .= $this->page_link($i, $query);
    }
    if($i < $count) {
        $links .= "...";
    }
    $links .= $this->page_link($count, $query);
    return($links);
}
private function page_link($num, $query) {
    return("<a href=\"search.php?page=" . $num . $query . "\" class=\"table_link\">" . $num . "</a>");
}
```